# How to modify existing panels in Maya using MEL or Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, panels, mel

I've been writing tools in Maya for years using MEL and Python.  I'd consider myself an expert in custom window/gui design in Maya except for one area; modifying existing panels and editors.

Typically, I'm building tools that need totally custom UIs, so its customary for me to build them from scratch.  However, recently I've found myself wanting to add some additional functionality to the layer editor in Maya.  I've seen tutorials that explain how to do this, but now that I want to do it, I can't find any.

Links to tutorials or a brief code snippet to get me started would be great.  I just need to know how to find the layer editor/panel and, say, add a button or text field to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried searching ui item names in MEL files under maya installation directory? It should be one of the MEL scripts included, and from there you can just modify it.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way can modify existing Maya code and put it in you user/script. You can use whatIs to get the script name. Say for eg:

```
whatIs "layerEditor";
```

Result is `./scripts/others/layerEditor.mel //` .But now you can use wrapping instance with PyQt also.

Comment: that `whatIs` command is like *the* most useful thing ever.. that and turning on 'echo all commands' in the script editor..

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but maybe someone still wants to find out.

I wrote this script at least 30 years ago: http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/downloads/scripts-plugins/interface-display/c/guihelper

Its horrible scripting-wise, but very useful for modifying Maya's Gui. You can add popup menus to all gui items with the item's name, commands to print hierachy etc; and you can load a window showing tthe gui control hierarchy.

Usually the trick is to identify a gui control that has a specific name, for example TimeSliderForm, and then traverse the hierachy to where you want to go, by querying the controls command, help text, label text etc.

Answer (score 1):

having just stumbled across your question, have you tried Digital Tutors Artists Guide to MEL?  Chapters 19-22 describe  step by step how to create your own custom GUI's and windows in Maya, here's the link:
http://www.digitaltutors.com/store/home.php?cat=82

Have fun.

Comment: I'll have to have a look.  I'm well versed in building custom windows from scratch, but modifying existing panels is the hard part.